# Full-width background positioned behind an element within Bootstrap container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, css-position

I've coded a pretty basic, two-column landing page with Bootstrap 3, using a container.

I wanted to have the entire page have two full-browser-width backgrounds, the top being a simple textured background, and the bottom being plain white, with a scalloped edge (a repeat-x background presumably positioned at the bottom of the top background's div) as a border between the two.

But what I want is for the background to transition exactly at the vertical point behind the middle of a particular button, which of course varies based on the browser window and the device (and the layout itself is responsive).

Is this even possible?

I've racked my brain and I'm not coming up with any rational solution given the container div, which is not full-width, and a few other divs above and below that button.

[image]

How would you go about this? Would love a CSS-only solution but a jQuery plugin would be fine, too.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Would some code help to illustrate what the content looks like?

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="row logo">
  <img src="/logo.png" class="col-md-2">
 </div> 

 <div class="row">
 <img src="/images/cookie.jpg" class="col-md-6">

  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <h1 class="headline">Text here</h1> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">Button text</button> <br />
     Some other stuff here
    </div>
  </div> <!-- main row -->

   <hr> 

    <div class="row footer">
    Some text
    </div> <!--footer row -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

Comment: It's kind of difficult to visualize based on what you've presented here, but could you absolutely position the button to the bottom of the top div, using `bottom: -15px` where 15 is exactly half of the button height?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/fMHRn/

Comment: It won't be responsive if so. The button is already within both a container and a col div, and in that div it comes after an h1 tag. Did I explain that correctly?

Comment: Yeah I totally see what you mean, it's just that all the content around the entire page is all relative and within columns and such. I think it could possibly work the other way around, with the background positioned absolutely behind the button, but I'm not sure how to do that and have it break out of the container div?

Comment: Do you have something live we could look at?

Comment: No, but I just edited the original post with some code... does that help illustrate how the content is laid out?

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could get from what I understood from your design goal.  Obviously, the design only works within a certain range and would require some design decisions (with media queries) to change the layout once those minimum and maximum width constraints are met.

http://jsfiddle.net/zyglobe/2tQGZ/5/

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container top">
    <p>Some text ipsum dolor sit amet volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Pellentesque molestie eleifend varius. Sed facilisis justo vitae tristique condimentum. Nulla imperdiet nulla vitae augue placerat, ac vulputate nisl volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <img class="bad" src="http://placehold.it/180x200">
  </div>
  <div class="container bottom">
    <button>Button</button>
    <p>Some text at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae. Suspendisse ornare in velit at molestie. Nam eu ligula a sem pulvinar viverra elementum eu ligula. Aenean posuere velit purus, eget luctus eros lacinia ut. Nam fringilla nulla sit amet neque consectetur, id euismod metus mattis. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image and button will need to be positioned relative to the border between the top and bottom containers. The rest of the content will need to be aware of this space and never intersect with it.

```
button {position:absolute;top:0;right:0px;height:40px;padding:0 20px;margin:-20px 40px 0 0;}

img.bad {position:absolute;bottom:-100px;left:14px;z-index:500;}

.top {padding:20px 10px 30px;}

.bottom {padding:30px 10px 20px;}
```

Apologies for the lazy styling. But you get the idea and can apply the proper semantics.  Hope this reference helps with your design challenge.

Comment: Thanks for this! It looks like a viable option. I'm going to work with it now, and let you know how it turns out!

Comment: Thanks again for this. I tried it out, but I really didn't want to rely on absolute positioning of the objects. I couldn't find a script or come up with any other solution, and I'd invested a good deal of time trying to figure it out already, so I had to use a half measure, which was absolutely positioning the background roughly behind the container and the button. It's not ideal, but unless anyone has another solution, sounds like it will have to do.